# How do I get the function pointer to a function restricted by a concept?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I have a function template and an overload for a concept:

```
template<typename T> void f() {std::cout<< "general" << std::endl;}
template<std::integral T> void f() {std::cout<< "integral" << std::endl;}
```

Now I want to get a function pointer to the function for the concept. It works fine when I use a helper struct:

```
typedef void (*tF)();

template<typename T> struct H
{
   static void g() {f<T>();}
};

tF fHd = &H<double>::g;
tF fHi = &H<int>::g;
```

When I do it directly without helper struct, like

```
tF fd = &f<double>;
tF fi = &f<int>;
```

GCC 10 gives an error message:

```
error: converting overloaded function ‘f’ to type ‘tF’ {aka ‘void (*)()’} is ambiguous

tF fi = &f<int>;
note: candidates are: ‘void f() [with T = int]’
  template<typename T> void f() {std::cout<< "general" << std::endl;}
note:                 ‘void f() [with T = int]’
   template<std::integral T> void f() {std::cout<< "integral" << std::endl;}
```

Is this a bug in GCC or is this required by the standard?

Comment: gcc bug, filed [95262](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95262).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that might be a bug right now, to get around it you can do something like...

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> void f() requires (!std::integral<T>) {std::cout<< "general" << std::endl;}
template<std::integral T> void f() {std::cout<< "integral" << std::endl;}

typedef void (*tF)();

int main() {
    tF fd = &f<double>;
    tF fi = &f<int>;
}
```

or even

```
template<typename T> concept nonIntegral = !std::integral<T>;

template<nonIntegral T> void f() {std::cout<< "general" << std::endl;}
template<std::integral T> void f() {std::cout<< "integral" << std::endl;}
```

and that should work fine.